# React Router: Invalid Hook Call when Using useState in index.tsx Instead of App.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to learn react router by following the below video but the problem is in my stackblitz there is no App.js.
So I have included everything inside index.tsx. but now I need to use this line  ---->  `const [user, setUser] = useState(null);`.

If I use this line I am getting the error, can you let me know how to fix it.

Error:
Providing my code snippet, sandbox and youtube tutorial below.

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9czykt?file=index.tsx,pages%2FProducts.tsx,pages%2FSingleProduct.tsx,pages%2FLogin.tsx,pages%2FDashboard.tsx,App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Demo from './Demo';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import About from './pages/About';
import Products from './pages/Products';
import Error from './pages/Error';
import SharedLayout from './pages/SharedLayout';
import SingleProduct from './pages/SingleProduct';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import Login from './pages/Login';

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';

const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      {/* <nav>our nav bar</nav> */}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<SharedLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="products" element={<Products />} />
          <Route path="products/:productId" element={<SingleProduct />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login setUser={setUser} />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login setUser={setUser} />} />

          <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
        </Route>
        {/* <Route path="dashboard" element={<div> dashboard</div>}>
          <Route path="stats" element={<div> stats</div>} />
        </Route> */}
      </Routes>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <Demo />
      </StyledEngineProvider>
      {/* <footer>our footer</footer> */}
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

> ### Only Call Hooks from React Functions
>
> **Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.** Instead, you can:
>
> - ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
> - ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks.

Create a root-level React component that can call the `useState` hook and render the router and routes.

Example:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Demo from './Demo';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import About from './pages/About';
import Products from './pages/Products';
import Error from './pages/Error';
import SharedLayout from './pages/SharedLayout';
import SingleProduct from './pages/SingleProduct';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import Login from './pages/Login';

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<SharedLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="products" element={<Products />} />
          <Route path="products/:productId" element={<SingleProduct />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login setUser={setUser} />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login setUser={setUser} />} />

          <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <Demo />
      </StyledEngineProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

createRoot(document.querySelector('#root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is with this part of the code `const [user, setUser] = useState(null);`. React hooks (such as `useState`) can only be used inside the body of a functional component.

Try moving the following part of your code to a separate component and also move `useState` to that component.

```
export const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {/* <nav>our nav bar</nav> */}
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<SharedLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
          <Route path='products' element={<Products />} />
          <Route path='products/:productId' element={<SingleProduct />} />
          <Route path='login' element={<Login setUser={setUser} />} />
          <Route path='login' element={<Login setUser={setUser} />} />

          <Route path='*' element={<Error />} />
        </Route>
        {/* <Route path="dashboard" element={<div> dashboard</div>}>
        <Route path="stats" element={<div> stats</div>} />
      </Route> */}
      </Routes>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <Demo />
      </StyledEngineProvider>
      {/* <footer>our footer</footer> */}
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```